# GMap Problem with Certain Browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm attempting to implement gMap [1] on a website and I've got it partially functioning.  The map shows up properly in Chrome and Safari but fails in Firefox, IE, and Opera (latest versions of all).  I have the Google Map API key loading as the first javascript resource in my header, followed by jQuery and then finally my call at window load (in aaolm.js).  Essentially what happens in the browsers that fail is that the map is partially rendered with the Google Maps controls but the actual map view is blank.  In Chrome and Safari the map renders with no problems. The below page is an example of what's happening:

http://www.advancedaquarist.com/events/reefstock-march-12-2011

I'm really at a loss as to why this is happening.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

[1] http://gmap.nurtext.de/examples.html

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well.  Seems that a very common "responsive design" technique (`img{max-width:100%;}`) is to blame.  If you can undo this by a `max-width: none;` on the images within the map `div`s, you're all set.

Answer (score 0):

Its going to be a div sizing issue..

Try making the div that contains your map a specific size, rather than 100%.. and you will probably find your map appears..

There's a bit of info here:

http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic19.htm

Duncan.

Comment: Thank you for the link!  I tried it out by setting an explicit width and height on the <div /> in the example above and unfortunately it didn't work as hoped.  I still end up with the same result in Firefox / IE.  In Chrome it's working fine as before.  The one thing I do notice is that it's hung on something -- I have the following in my status bar "transferring data from mt0.google.com." Googling wasn't much help on that either.